# wp_list_pages isnt showing title attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, list, wordpress-theming

I'm using wordpress on my site and for some reason the wp_list_pages() isn't showing a title attribute?

I'd love to add it for the SEO purposes.

Any help?

My current code is

```
wp_list_pages('depth=1&title_li=&exclude=9');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wp_list_pages()` not supposed to have a title attribute by default. You can always write your own functions if the given functions don't fit your needs.

```
<?php 
function mytheme_list_pages($param) {
  $pages = get_pages($param); 
  foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $li  = '<li><a href="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '" title="';
    $li .= esc_attr($page->post_title);
    $li .= '">';
    $li .= $page->post_title;
    $li .= '</a></li>';
    echo $li;
  }
}
?>
```

Place this in your themes function.php and use it instead of `wp_list_pages()`. If you are using a standard wordpress theme I recommend creating a child theme for this, since theme updates will remove your changes in the future. Feel free to add any ids and classes as you need them.
It gets a little more complicated when you add css classes like `current_page_item` for the currently visible page to the generated HTML markup.

Answer (score -1):

'post_title.'">%s%s%s',

```html
add this code wp-includes/post-template.php  line number  1345

'<li class="%s"><a href="%s" title="'.$page->post_title.'">%s%s%s</a>',
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example from the Wordpress codex.

In the following example, only Pages with IDs 9, 5, and 23 are included in the list and the heading text has been changed to the word "Poetry", with a heading style of :

```
   <ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('include=5,9,23&title_li=<h2>' . __('Poetry') . '</h2>' ); ?>
  </ul>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OPs question.