# wp_list_pages with title-attribute (just child_of_parent)

Tags: wordpress, post, children

i need help with wp_list_pages (wordpress).

I want to show all children pages under a parent on page.php
With this code its work fine but i get no title-attribute:

```
<?php
    if($post->post_parent) {
        // show all child of parent, exclude self
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0&exclude=".$post->ID."");
        $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->post_parent);
    } else {
        // show all child of parent
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
        $titlenamer = get_the_title($post->ID);
    }

    if ($children) { ?>
        <h2><?php echo $titlenamer; ?></h2>
        <ul id="zp_list_pages">
            <?php echo $children; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php } 
?>
```

After a search i found this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353076/wp-list-pages-isnt-showing-title-attribute) but this show all pages, not just the children.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your `title_li=` is blank...

Comment: Oh sorry,

i meant the hyperlink title-attribute, not the list title.